# Proof of cancellation law for vector addition

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I have a question regarding the proof of the cancellation law for vector addition. This theorem states:

If $x,y,$ and $z$ are vectors in a vector space V such that $x+z=y+z$, then $x=y$.

The proof is as follows:

There exists a vector $v$ in V such that $z+v=0$. Thus

$x=x+0=x+(z+v)=(x+z)+v=(y+z)+v=y+(z+v)=y+0=y$.

My question lies with this equality:

$(x+z)+v=(y+z)+v$.

How can we replace $(x+z)$ with $(y+z)$ and claim to prove anything? Is this equality not contingent on the very thing we are attempting to prove?

Answer (score 3):

**It is given** that $x+z=y+z$. So, we can definitely use in our proof.

> ...$\rm V$ such that $x+z=y+z$, then...

Comment: I think this is an excellent answer. "It is given" is exactly the point.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Why, it perfectly answers the question

Comment: @TheSimpliFire The question is why _'can we replace $(x+z)$ with $(y+z)$'_, and the answer is perfectly correct: _we can_ because **that is assured in the assumption given**.